# What are the different stories in different scriptures regarding birth and loss off head of Lord Vinayaka?

Tags: puranas, ganesha

I heard that different Puranas have different stories regarding how Vinayaka was born and lost his head and how he gained a new head.

1. I'd like to know the names of the Purnas that describe these
   incidents and maybe a few deatils about verses that describe these.

So, I can find these and read these.

Comment: Hello! 1. You are asking multiple questions in a single post. Please limit your question to a single topic. It is also a list question where there is no end of answers. Visit [ask] section from [help]. 2.  This question is already asked [Why does Lord Ganesha have an elephant head?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/315/5212). Any new answer will go to that question. That answer has various versions of the same story. So, it's a duplicate..

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7310/why-didnt-lord-shiva-put-back-the-original-head-of-lord-ganesha - check out last answer!